# Join Query for fetching the Count

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

**tbl_TransactionDishout**

```
Trnx_id   offerNo   TerminalID      Created                  VirtualCard
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1         1014      170924690436418 2010-05-25 12:51:59.547  1234567890
2         1014      123924690436418 2010-05-23 12:51:59.547  1234567890
3         1015      144524690436418 2010-05-23 12:51:59.547  1234567890
```

**tbl_Offer**

```
OFID    Offer_Text   
------------------
1014    Test1   
1015    Test2
```

Now I want the Output to be like this:

```
OFID    Offer_Text     Counter
------------------------------
1014    Test1          2
1015    Test2          1
```

Is it possible with the single query..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select t2.OFID, cast(t2.Offer_Text as varchar(max)), Count(*)
from tbl_TransactionDishout t
inner join tbl_Offer t2 on cast(t.offerNo as varchar(max)) = cast(t2. OFID as varchar(max))
group by t2.OFID, cast(t2.Offer_Text as varchar(max))
```

Comment: Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'tbl_Offer.Offer_Text' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this

```
SELECT     O.OFID, O.Offer_Text, COUNT(t.offerNo) AS Counter FROM  tbl_Offer AS O 
INNER JOIN  tbl_TransactionDishout AS t ON O.OFID = t.offerNo GROUP BY O.OFID, O.Offer_Text
```

EDIT :

The following is the output screen shot when I tried it in my system.

[image]

Comment: you need to add group by clause. This statement will throw an error.

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'tbl_Offer.OFID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @VishalSuthar, copy the full query and try... I tried it in my sys, its working simply fine.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this one , it will work

```
 select t1.OFID,t1.Offer_text, count(t2.offerNo)
 from tbl_Offer t1 inner join tbl_TransactionDishout t2 
 on t1.OFID= t2.offerNo
 group by t1.OFID,t1.Offer_text
```

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'tbl_Offer.OFID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: yes. for that instead of using direct column name, u can use alias name as t for tbl_Offer, t1 for another table and make join .

Comment: You need to add group by clause.

Comment: run query without group by, and tell me what you got?

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.offerNo,Offer_Text,COUNT(a.TerminalID) as Counter
from 
tbl_TransactionDishout a,
tbl_Offer b
where a.OFID = b.OFID
group by OFID,Offer_Text;
```

Comment: Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: Check now. I edited the answer. can you show your table structure, is offerNo and OFID  a text?

Comment: Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead. Can you explain why you use text instead of varchar.?

Comment: In sql server, varchar is the same as text...There is nothing like text data type in sql server...It is there in MS ACCESS

Comment: I dont think varchar is same as text in sql server, There is text data type in sql server Check this for text = http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993(v=sql.90).aspx and varchar = http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
select OFID, Offer_Text, Trnx_id as Counter from tbl_offer left join tbl_TransactionDishout  on transactionDishout.offerNo = tbl_Offer.OfferText ordered by Trnx_id desc
```